# applying background style to single elements safari

Tags: javascript, safari

So, every item I produce gets an individual style=`background: url(${[this guy's image url]}) [blahblahblah]`

It works in other browsers but not Safari!
In Safari, none of the images show up (and there's no element.style tool in its developer tools)

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting the url in single quotes like this:

```
background: url('http://some-url.domain/picture.png')
```